# is there a key command to jump by capitalized word

Tags: xcode

If I have something like

```
aBigLongVariableThatIWantToChangeASpecificWordIn
```

Is there a key command that can jump me from word to word so that I can quickly get in and replace a particular word?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, Control+Left/Right will jump between capitalized letters in a single variable name.  Control+Shift+Left/Right will select to the next capitalized letter.

Option+Left/Right jumps between complete words.

Comment: wow..  why is it that ctrl-Left/Right on my machine (running mountain lion) does absolutely nothing?

Answer (score -1):

In xcode, click Apple CMD + F ... then click replace.. type in whatever function you have and replace all with the new function name

Comment: This answer has nothing related to the question.